# Docker fails to add ppa

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, android, docker

I am trying to run an example from tvm tutorials, the one for [deploying a pretrained model on android](https://docs.tvm.ai/_downloads/51356ac7bc3aea4c14e21daccf2bcb1b/deploy_model_on_android.py), they advise using the docker the given docker image because of android package dependencies. The problem is that building fails for me with the error:

```
docker build -t tvm.demo_android -f docker/Dockerfile.demo_android ./docker
  (things happening...)
  Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~jonathonf/ubuntu/python-3.6'.
  Error: '~jonathonf' user or team does not exist.
```

I am running ubuntu 16.04 with a corporate proxy (configured for http and https in *.bashrc*) so maybe the problem come from that... But I have configured it for docker with environments set in */etc/systemd/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf*, respectively *https-proxy.conf*.

Some quirks that happened before with the proxy: I had to set the https proxy to http in order to login with docker. I have tried building the docker image with the true https proxy and http one without success.

Maybe the repository changed name, I don't know where I have looked at the Dockerfile and I don't know where I can change this, here it is:

```
# Minimum docker image for demo purposes
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing

COPY install/ubuntu_install_core.sh /install/ubuntu_install_core.sh
RUN bash /install/ubuntu_install_core.sh

COPY install/ubuntu_install_python.sh /install/ubuntu_install_python.sh
RUN bash /install/ubuntu_install_python.sh

COPY install/ubuntu_install_python_package.sh /install/ubuntu_install_python_package.sh
RUN bash /install/ubuntu_install_python_package.sh

COPY install/ubuntu_install_keras.sh /install/ubuntu_install_keras.sh
RUN bash /install/ubuntu_install_keras.sh

COPY install/ubuntu_install_java.sh /install/ubuntu_install_java.sh
RUN bash /install/ubuntu_install_java.sh

COPY install/ubuntu_install_llvm.sh /install/ubuntu_install_llvm.sh
RUN bash /install/ubuntu_install_llvm.sh

COPY install/ubuntu_install_gradle.sh /install/ubuntu_install_gradle.sh
RUN bash /install/ubuntu_install_gradle.sh

COPY install/ubuntu_install_androidsdk.sh /install/ubuntu_install_androidsdk.sh
RUN bash /install/ubuntu_install_androidsdk.sh

COPY install/ubuntu_install_vulkan.sh /install/ubuntu_install_vulkan.sh
RUN bash /install/ubuntu_install_vulkan.sh

ENV VULKAN_SDK /usr/local/VulkanSDK/1.0.65.0/x86_64
ENV PATH ${PATH}:${VULKAN_SDK}/bin
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${VULKAN_SDK}/lib
ENV VK_LAYER_PATH ${VULKAN_SDK}/etc/explicit_layer.d

# Build TVM
RUN cd /usr && \
    git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/dmlc/tvm --recursive && \
    cd /usr/tvm && \
    mkdir -p build && \
    cd build && \
    cmake \
        -DUSE_LLVM=llvm-config-6.0 \
        -DUSE_RPC=ON \
        -DUSE_SORT=ON \
        -DUSE_GRAPH_RUNTIME=ON \
        -DUSE_VULKAN=ON \
        .. && \
    make -j10

# Environment variables
ENV PYTHONPATH=/usr/tvm/python:/usr/tvm/topi/python:/usr/tvm/nnvm/python/:/usr/tvm/vta/python:${PYTHONPATH}
```

Hope that was clear enough.
Thanks.

Comment: The PPA is [here](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.6): can you access it from the container (`docker run -it <image> curl https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.6`)?

Comment: Sorry I am not used to docker, the command tells me that it does not find curl (although it is installed on my machine). I have tried with 'docker run -it ubuntu ...', but I don't think the image is already built. Do I need to configure a Dockerfile or download something before? Because I thought maybe it has some prebuilt images that it will automatically download.

Comment: Ok, I have tried running ubuntu image first and then installing curl;, then doing the curl, it blocks, probably due to the proxy. So I guessI should configure the proxy environments in the images from the example

Comment: Ok I have understood how Docker works, sorry for the useless posting...
I created my image from ubuntu with curl installed, running the command you have given actually works because, the https proxy was set to a bad value.
It seams to wor seamlessly now.
Thank you.